# Alterar valor padrão de um parâmetro em uma função, é possível?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Tenho um array de funções, e preciso alterar o valor padrão do parâmetro com outro valor para cada uma delas, em um loop.. isso é possível? Ex:

```js
var externalValidations = [
  function required(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  },
  
  function requiredTwo(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  },
]

externalValidations.forEach(item => {
  // --> Consigo aqui de alguma forma alterar o valor padrão de um parâmetro para cada função?!.. para ela ficar assim por exemplo: 
  // function requiredTwo(v, model = {valor1: 'valor1'}) {
  //   console.log(model)

  //   return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  // },
  console.log(item)
})
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece uma situação meio enrolada, mas no cenário descrito eu resolveria substituindo as funções do array por novas, que envelopam as originais. Assim:

```
var externalValidations = [
  function required(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  },

  function requiredTwo(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  },
];

for (let i=0; i<externalValidations.length; i++) {
    let original = externalValidations[i];
    externalValidations[i] = (v, model = {foo: 'bar'}) => original(v, model);
}
```

Comment: Legal Brother, graças sua ajuda cheguei a uma solução aqui! Obrigado!